# Swift closure memory usage

Tags: ios, swift, closures

Using a closure is causing memory pressure and app to be terminated by the debugger for memory issues. Here is the simple closure I define and pass it as an argument to different functions. The memory pressure disappears if I replace the closure with two lines of code in the closure where ever it is needed. Will this closures passed to function retain `outputPixelBuffer` or `sampleBuffer` passed in the arguments indefinitely?

```
let videoProcessor: (CMSampleBuffer, CVPixelBuffer) throws -> Void = { (sampleBuffer, outputPixelBuffer) in
    if let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer), CFGetTypeID(imageBuffer) == CVPixelBufferGetTypeID() {
        do {
            try delegate.processPixelBuffer(self, inputPixelBuffer: imageBuffer, toPixelBuffer: outputPixelBuffer)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed processing pixel buffer")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're capturing a strong reference to self, causing a loop. Add a capture list - [weak self] before the parameters of the closure, then inside you can include

```
let strongself = self
```

and then replace all references to self (even currently implicit) with strongself. I'm not on a device where I can readily just edit your code, but this should do it.

Comment: It does not unfortunately. It's not about self but the closure that is passed around and holds the buffers I suspect.

Comment: I think it is not about the closure, there is memory pressure built sometimes without closure. Need to debug it.

Comment: Try to replace `{ (sampleBuffer, outputPixelBuffer) in` with `{ [weak self] (sampleBuffer, outputPixelBuffer) in` and add the corresponding `?` (XCode should hints it). But the also the processing might be consuming to much memory (do it in a release pool ?)?

Comment: There is a Core Image filter chain, I doubt if memory consumption is coming from there. New Allocations tool is too complex in XCode 10 to figure out anything.

Comment: Maybe use XCode 9 then if the 10th is too complex (if it's still possible). Also, check before hand if you don't have Memory Leaks. Then, check the allocations.

Comment: Used Leaks tool, no leaks but memory usage is spiking from 100 MB to 400 MB when using 3820x2160 sample video as input for filtering.